# How can I restrict the user not to access login page after logged in with Laravel Guards?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am building a project with Laravel. Everything is fine with my codes, just when the user is logged in he can access the dashboard but the problem is when I hit in url of login it is going back and showing the login form page again when I hit the url of dashboard it is showing me the dashboard.

As we know that in Facebook after we have logged in we cannot access the login page again, but if we logout then we can see, so I want that same feature in my project. Here in below is my codes as far I have done,

Routes

```
Route::prefix('/admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function(){

    // All the Admin Routes
    Route::match(['get','post'],'/','AdminController@login');
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
        Route::get('dashboard','AdminController@dashboard');
        Route::get('logout','AdminController@logout');
    });

});
```

Controller

```
 public function login(Request $request){
        if($request->isMethod('post')){

            $data = $request->all();
            // echo "<pre>";
            // print_r($data);
            // die;
            $this->validate($request,[
                'email'=>'required',
                'password'=>'required',
            ],
            );
            
            if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password']])){
                return redirect('admin/dashboard');
            }else{
                // $request->session()->flash('error', 'Invalid email or password');
                Session::flash('error','Invalid email or password');
                return redirect()->back();
            }

        }
        return view('admin.admin_login');
    }

    public function logout(){
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        return redirect('/admin');
    }
```

Middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!Auth::guard('admin')->check()){
            return redirect('/admin');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
    ];
```

Comment: how did you register your middleware?

Comment: I have registered in kernel.php

Comment: yes, in that file there are many places you can register it, you need to provide where you put it,

Comment: Okay i am updating my post

Answer (score 2):

Assign the `guest` middleware to any route you do not want an authenticated user to reach. You can pass a guard name to it:

```
'guest:admin'
```

Comment: You can see `Route::match(['get','post'],'/','AdminController@login');` do you think it will be the perfect route to do that

Comment: well it probably shouldn't be handling multiple HTTP methods, but yea; any route you do not want an authenticated user to reach you would use the `guest` middleware on, that is what it is for

Comment: okay, that is what that middleware is for, good luck

Answer (score 1):

create special middleware for access login page and set cookie or create session when session or cookie exist route must redirect  to dashboard else show login page

Answer (score 1):

**check redirectifauthenticated.php**

and set the route accordingly as you wished

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    { 
      switch ($guard) {
        case 'admin':
          if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
          }
          break;
        case 'writer':
          if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect()->route('writer.dashboard');
          }
          break;
        default:
          if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
              return redirect('/home'); 
          }
          break;
      }

      return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it.

//Create the middleware if not exists

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated 
{ 
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                //redirect to where you want
                return redirect(url('dashboard'));
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

//Then use the middleware in pages you don't want logged in users to access like this

```
Route::get('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register'])->name("register")
    ->middleware(RedirectIfAuthenticated::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this route method

```
Route::get('/login', function () {
    //
})->middleware('guest:admin');
```

Or use in controller like this

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->only(['edit']);
    }
```

or

```
public function __construct()
{
     $this->middleware('guest:admin')->only('login');
}
```

I am doing with your code

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
// Define Middleware here like this 
public function __construct()
{
     $this->middleware('guest:admin')->only('login');
}

public function login(Request $request){
        if($request->isMethod('post')){

            $data = $request->all();
            // echo "<pre>";
            // print_r($data);
            // die;
            $this->validate($request,[
                'email'=>'required',
                'password'=>'required',
            ],
            );
            
            if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password']])){
                return redirect('admin/dashboard');
            }else{
                // $request->session()->flash('error', 'Invalid email or password');
                Session::flash('error','Invalid email or password');
                return redirect()->back();
            }

        }
        return view('admin.admin_login');
    }

    public function logout(){
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        return redirect('/admin');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have seen my login route `Route::match(['get','post'],'/','AdminController@login');`

Comment: Yes I have seen them. You can use in controller in your loginController  /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
    }


    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('admin');
    }

Comment: I have noticed that you are using only one controller for all routes. You can use them like laravel auth controllers. Separate for each method. I have used them like this

Comment: No This AdminController is just for the login. Results are the same as before

Comment: Problem is with your controllers and routes. I am updating the answer

Comment: With my codes if i use login post route in `Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {`  it works but i donot want to separate the get and post because all of my codes are running well

Comment: Yes i told you that this thing is working if i separate down the get and post if both of them are used along then how to do but Thanks

Comment: Do you have got any idea how to do them along with match

Comment: It should work with match too. Are you getting any error when you applied in the controller?

Comment: Yes i am facing the same problem